Increasing sequences and Wieferich primes
We are trying to show that primes of the form $a(n)$ can't be
Wieferich primes.
For natural $n$ define $J(n)=(2^{n-1}-1) \bmod n^2$
and if $n$ is power of two define $J(2^n)=1$ (this is artificial, just to
avoid triviality and by $\bmod$ we mean take the smallest residue modulo $n^2$).
Prime $p$ is Wieferich prime iff $J(p)=0$.

Q1 Is there increasing sequence $a(n)$ which conjecturally has
infinitely many primes and $J(a(n))$ is increasing, thus non-zero?


Q2 Is there intuitive explanation why  $J(20 \cdot 18^n+19)$ is increasing up
to $n=3985$ and then fail?

Dropping the prime requirements, limited experiments suggest
$\log\log{J({2^{2^n}}+1)} \sim n$

Q3 Is $J({B^{2^n}}+1)$ increasing for some $B$?


I will focus on Q3. Let us evaluate $J(2^{2^n}+1)$. Denote $N=2^{2^n}+1$. Then $N-1=2^{2^n}$. Notice that $2^{2^{n+1}}\equiv 1 \pmod N$. Let $M=\frac{N-1}{2^{n+1}}=2^{2^n-n-1}$, which is an integer. We have
$$
2^{N-1}-1=2^{M2^{n+1}}-1=
$$
$$=(2^{2^{n+1}}-1)(2^{(M-1)2^{n+1}}+2^{(M-2)2^{n+1}}+\cdots+1).
$$
The first factor is divisible by $N$, and the second is $\equiv M\pmod N$, hence
$$
2^{N-1}-1\equiv M(2^{2^{n+1}}-1) \pmod {N^2}.
$$
Note also that $N^2=2^{2^{n+1}}+2^{2^n+1}+1$. Hence
$$
2^{N-1}-1\equiv -2MN \pmod {N^2}.
$$
Now, $M$ is, of course, much smaller than $N$, so
$$
2^{N-1}-1\equiv N^2-2MN \pmod {N^2}
$$
This means that $J(N)=N^2(1-2M/N)=N^2(1-O(2^{-n}))$. In particular, $J(2^{2^n}-1)\sim 2^{2^{n+1}}$.

Thanks. So you showed that Fermat number $2^{2^n}+1$ can't be Wieferich prime because of non vanishing of $J(N)$, right?

@joro, yes, but it is conjectured that there are finitely many Fermat primes, so this does not answer Q1

Indeed, but Q1 is very hard. Is there hope to generalize your result to other doubly exponential sequences like $B^{2^n}+1$ for even B not a power of two?
